# Swift: Overlay NxN grid of buttons of aspect fit image

Tags: ios, swift

Tried searching for a while but couldn't find a way to do this.

I currently have a uiimage that is aspect fit. I'm trying to overlay a NxN grid of buttons over the image.

My thought process was to find the boundaries of the image in the imageview, and then overlay the buttons based off those boundaries. I usually use storyboards but am taking a stab at this programmatically as I couldn't figure out the aspect fit part in storyboards.

I found this code for finding the boundaries of my image after its been fit and did some print statements to be sure that it is finding the correct boundaries which I believe it is.

```
extension UIImageView {
var contentClippingRect: CGRect {
    guard let image = image else { return bounds }
    guard contentMode == .scaleAspectFit else { return bounds }
    guard image.size.width > 0 && image.size.height > 0 else { return bounds }

    let scale: CGFloat
    if image.size.width > image.size.height {
        scale = bounds.width / image.size.width
    } else {
        scale = bounds.height / image.size.height
    }

    let size = CGSize(width: image.size.width * scale, height: image.size.height * scale)
    let x = (bounds.width - size.width) / 2.0
    let y = (bounds.height - size.height) / 2.0

    return CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: size.width, height: size.height)
}
```

}

I'm currently trying to initialize the stackview by passing the image.contentRectClipping frame to it. My understanding would be that this would create a frame based off the x,y,width and height and I would be good to go. However it places the stackview in the top left of the imageview and not the actual image. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? I haven't found a solution for this in the last 4 years...